# KDE - change the look of buttons, radios, etc

Tags: kde

I'm using KDE. Is it possible to change the default look of buttons, context menus and other common components?

For example, this is a fragment of settings. I'd like the button to be 'flatter', maybe MaterialUI-ish.

I'm not asking about exact customization, using themes made by other people would be just as cool. Changing the `global theme` doesn't seem to impact anything besides the buttons' colors.

[image]

Comment: have you tried the plasma themes (not same as global themes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kvantum themes allow for customizing all of this.